# Keep the DataFrame index name after appending, a list of Series?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, indexing, naming

I want to keep the `name` of the `index` of this `DataFrame` after `append`ing a `list` of `Series`, as it is kept after appending them one at a time, but:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[3,4]],index = pd.Index(['a','b'],name='keepthisname'))
              0  1
keepthisname      
a             1  2
b             3  4

serc = pd.Series([5,6],name='c')
0    5
1    6
Name: c, dtype: int64

dfc = df.append(serc)  # one at a time works
              0  1
keepthisname      
a             1  2
b             3  4
c             5  6
serd = pd.Series([7,8],name='d')  # as further evidenced with this...
dfc.append(serd)
              0  1
keepthisname      
a             1  2
b             3  4
c             5  6
d             7  8

df.append([serc,serd])  # but this wipes out the name of the index
   0  1
a  1  2
b  3  4
c  5  6
d  7  8
```

Comment: Are you trying `df.reset_index().join([serc,serd])`? Looks to me like you are after a join. Your desired output sample?

Comment: Executing your code produces nothing like the desired (second to last) output.

Comment: `df.append([serc,serd]).rename_axis(index=df.index.name)`.

Comment: OK.  thanks for the workaround for what appears to be a bug.